# AfterUpdate trigger on Account after Lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

I have an `after update` trigger on `Account` object. I use the record's fields from `Trigger.New` but one field is empty in the context of this trigger.

Accounts are created from Lead conversion.

This field is well mapped in the `Lead conversion` settings and not empty on the Lead (also available on the created Account object after conversion).

Any idea why this field "not copied yet" inside the after update context?

```
Lead(
 Field__c = 'test'
)

=== Lead conversion ===> (Account.Field__c = Lead.Field__c)

On record page:

Account(
 Field__c = 'test'
)

On after update trigger (kicked by a WorkFlow Rule):

Account(
 Field__c = null
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after update" trigger being kicked by a workflow rule?

Comment: Are you sure the workflow rule is firing when lead conversion creates the account?   I assume you've tested your afterUpdate trigger by manually updating an account?